# Difficulties with Gradients

Tags: adobe-photoshop, gradient

I'm having some difficulties with Gradients... again. There's this image with the artwork of a bezel in which the artist simply "dropped the brush", guess that's an appropriate analogy, with the colour of the lens' case in the bezel's metalon (the "body"), causing a very distinguishable stain:

[image]

I tried some different approaches I know but I couldn't get a decent result because of the gradient, so I ended up deciding to paint the whole thing as close as possible. I masked only what you can see above and build a Gradient definition very close to the original. I could share the .GRD file but I don't know how.

But no matter the direction I drew my Linear Gradient I couldn't get anything even close to this.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is that what your aiming for of youf attempt? Anyway its impossible to know what you did wrong because you dont tell it.

Comment: This is the original. I was trying to clean this beige stain in the bottom-left part (and later the green on top-right) and the first idea I had was to redo the whole gradient since Content-Aware/Patch would help me with given the complexity of the surroundings.

Answer (score 1):

here's one trick that can be useful

[image]

1. The original with so large errors that one cannot fix them with the cloning brush
2. Original is rotated and warped to get a good straight slice. Its about just below the arrow.
3. The slice is selected and pasted to a new layer
4. The slice is stretched horizontally
5. The stretched slice is warped to the needed form. It can be used as is or as a cloning source to fix the errors in the original.

**Before trying this** try at first to push good color over the bad with the smudge brush and the cloning brush. Work in a copied layer. Limit the affected area with a selection.

This is the result of two minutes smudging & cloning (not a masterpiece, needs much steadier hand than I have)

[image]

Comment: And the Ockham's Razor strikes again. The simplest solution is usually the correct or at least the most suitable. I haven't even considered this warping technique. But I'll certainly try the second procedure first. For now, thank you for your time. :)